# Checking to see if each value in one dataset is equal to ANY value in another dataset column

Tags: sas

I have one dataset (mydata) with id, name, start_date, end_date, and code. Then i Have another dataset (codes) which only has one column, which is codelist.  I want to find a way to see if the code of each individual person matches ANY of the codes in the codelist (between january 1st 2004 and december 31st 2005). I tried to put all the codes from the codelist into a macro variable list but there are too many code in the codelist and so it gets truncated...

this is my code so far:

```
 proc sql noprint; 
     select distinct * 
     into : codelist separated by ' '
     from codes
 quit;  

data 20042005; set mydata codes;
match = 0;
    if code in (%codelist) AND start_date >= '01jan2004'd AND end_date <='31dec2005'd
    THEN match = 1;
run;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

thanks :)

Comment: How does the codes table look? Do you have multiple columns or a single column.  If codes are character you would need to quote the variable so something like the following instead: proc sql; select distinct quote(code) into : codelist separated by  ' ' from codes; quit;

Comment: all codes are numerical. just the one single column in both datasets. I just want to see if each value of code in the mydata dataset matches ANY of the values in the codelist dataset. Does that help clear things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sql left join to check the variables. You may need to add conditions to either the case statement or where clause:

```
DATA CODES;
    DO CODE=1 TO 100;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
RUN;

DATA MY_CODES;
    DO CODE=50 TO 150;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
RUN;

Proc sql;
Create Table Check as
select a.*, case when a.code=b.code then 1
                else 0 end as match
from MY_CODES a
left join codes b
on a.code=b.code;
quit;
```

Comment: won't a 'left join' join the tables in a way that only one code from the codelist will be assigned to one person from mydata set?

in basic terms i just want to do:
select code from mydata. search through the other dataset as if its a list. if the code from mydata equal ANY of the codes from the codelist, create a new variable called match that will equal 1. Repeat down the rows for all observations in mydata.

Comment: No, any code in the first table (left) will find a match if its in the second table. Try it :)